# How to convert Java LinkedHashMap to Scala LinkedHashMap?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm new to Scala. I've been trying to convert a java LinkedHashMap to an equivalent collection(LinkedHashMap?) in Scala in order to preserve the insertion order.

Tried following things as suggested in other threads, but nothing seems to work!

`scalaAsMap()` - is messing up the order

`TreeMap()` - sort on keys, values, etc. is not something I'm looking for

Explicit conversion is not working.

```
val f = new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, java.util.Map[String, String]]

var g: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, java.util.Map[String, String]] = f
```

Comment: Use JavaConverters. See this [doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, how about:

```
val javaMap = new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, String]()
val scalaMap = javaMap.asScala
```

The type of scalaMap is Map[String, String] but under the hood it behaves just like LinkedHashMap.

Comment: javaMap.asScala is preserving the order of java map.

Comment: However this converts Map into a regular map. See the following error:  type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]]
required: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]]